# Exchange 2016, multiple domains, correct DKIM setup?

Tags: exchange, dkim

Our Exchange 2016 server and set up is a bit of a mess, but the short of it is that we have numerous domains configured in it, including multiple separate business divisions that probably should have their own mail server. DKIM was never set up on it when the contractor installed it, so I'm trying to do that now.

For illustration, the Exchange server is set up primarily as business1.com and I set up DKIM for business2.com.   When I send an email to Gmail, it says it was encrypted by business2.com (correct) but Gmail still flags the email because even though the email FROM is me@business2.com, it sees business1.com all over the sending headers so I still get the broken red lock and "company1.com did not encrypt this message".

company2 has an SPF record with company1 listed as an approved alternate sender:
`v=spf1 a mx mx:company1.com ~all`

I'm using this DKIM agent, as it seems to be the most popular and trusted:
https://github.com/Pro/dkim-exchange

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Further research points to maybe this not being a DKIM issue, but just to clarify so you don't think I'm a complete idiot. :)     As I understand it, DKIM is two parts.. on the mail server, it signs the outgoing emails.  Coupled with a public key in a TXT DNS record, remove servers can verify that the email was sent by the server it claims to have come from.    In the headers, all the various checks PASS (DKIM, SPF, DMARC, etc).   But in Gmail, there's a broken red lock and a message that says "company1" didn't encrypt the message.  I took that to mean "yeah, it's signed.. and the signature validates per the TXT record, but it wasn't from the email server the email originated from".   Now it seems like it's indicating that the email server didn't encrypt the message (not sign, but actually encrypt the whole thing) while transmitting to Google.   That's a different issue than I initially thought.   So I guess my question isn't the correct question.  Thanks for your responses!

Comment: It is unclear what your DKIM setup actually is based on your question so this part cannot be answered. *"....  company1.com did not encrypt this message"* - DKIM and SPF are completely unrelated to encryption. In summary it is not clear for me what you are actually asking: do you want to know about DKIM (as in the title) or do you want to know why the mail shows as not encrypted (as seems to be your point in the body of the question).

Comment: The red openend lock is about TLS encryption, which encrypts the message in transport. DKIM encrypts certain headers and points to a DNS location where the receiving server can find the public key to decrypt the headers to proof authenticity. Gmail does not have any visual aids for DKIM failure, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Steffen Ullrich, you may need to clarify your question for further troubleshooting.

According to my research, the way DKIM verifying is done by the receiving part domain if the DKIM is configured in that recipient domain. If at all there is no DKIM configured no DKIM verification will be performed on the receiver and the mail will be routed normally to the recipient. For more details: [On-Premises Exchange: DKIM and DMARC setup](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35595.on-premises-exchange-dkim-and-dmarc-setup.aspx#How_DKIM_Works)

Configure [DKIM](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fasttracktips/2016/07/16/spf-dkim-dmarc-and-exchange-online/) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Further research points to maybe this not being a DKIM issue, but just to clarify so you don't think I'm a complete idiot. :) As I understand it, DKIM is two parts.. on the mail server, it signs the outgoing emails. Coupled with a public key in a TXT DNS record, remove servers can verify that the email was sent by the server it claims to have come from. In the headers, all the various checks PASS (DKIM, SPF, DMARC, etc). But in Gmail, there's a broken red lock and a message that says "company1" didn't encrypt the message. I took that to mean "yeah, it's signed.. and the signature validates per the TXT record, but it wasn't from the email server the email originated from". Now it seems like it's indicating that the email server didn't encrypt the message (not sign, but actually encrypt the whole thing) while transmitting to Google. That's a different issue than I initially thought. So I guess my question isn't the correct question. Thanks for your responses!